# Trying to convert time 19 digits

Tags: time

I am wondering what they formats are? Any advice would be much appreciated. This is used in the IBM application called Tealeaf

```
4682158116698062848 = 12:00:00 AM
4682162239866667008 = 12:01:00 AM
4682166363035271168 = 12:02:00 AM
4682405506814312448 = 01:00:00 AM
```

If I have to use an application to convert it, then the choice would be PHP

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Microsoft OLE Automation timestamp. [Here is Microsoft's page about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx). It represents the number of 24 hour periods since 1 Jan. 1900.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 64+ bit stamps.  The most significant 28+bits are the seconds about 788 days after some epoch (Jan 1, 1970??) which would make it Feb 28, 1972 - or possible some other encoding  based on seconds.  The least significant 36-bits are all 0.  I would expect the values could reach `pow(2,72)` or 22 decimal digits.